# 500 internal server error in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have created a new Laravel project. But when I run the command **php artisan serve** in the browser I am getting an **500 internal server error** with no error log from Laravel even if debug mode is set to true. Please suggest.

Comment: can you check your apache log error, or laravel storage/logs file

Comment: Hi I checked laravel.log file. There is no error logged.

Comment: how about apache error log? are you using xamp??

Comment: I am a beginner to Laravel. From cmd I am running the command php artisan serve to launch the application in browser using localhost:8000/

Answer (score 1):

Found similar issue on laracasts:-

[[SOLVED] [L5] New: Can't display errors, 500 internal server error](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/new-cant-display-errors)

It's been fixed by enabling write permission to storage folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: True this worked for me. What does that mean by enabling write permission , any security issue will be there?